# IOError: closed stream when using Selenium + Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, minitest

I want to use Selenium with mit Rails 4.1.5 app (using mintest, not RSpec)

In the test-helper I have

```
"require 'minitest/rails/capybara'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'minitest/autorun'"
```

(and more).

In the actual test-file in the test/features folder I have

"require_relative '../test_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers

```
feature 'Admin Backend' do
  let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create :admin }

  before { login_as admin }

  scenario 'Administrating Offers' do
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
    organization = FactoryGirl.create :organization

    visit rails_admin_path

    click_link 'Angebote', match: :first
    click_link 'Neu hinzufügen'

    assert_difference 'Offer.count', 1 do
      fill_in 'offer_name', with: 'testangebot'
      fill_in 'offer_description', with: 'testdescription'
      fill_in 'offer_next_steps', with: 'testnextsteps'
      select 'Fixed', from: 'offer_encounter'
      select organization.name, from: 'offer_organization_id'

      click_button 'Speichern'
      page.must_have_content 'testangebot'
    end
  end
end"
```

If I run the test I get

"1) Error:
Example Feature Test#test_0001_Administrating Offers:
IOError: closed stream
    test/features/example_test.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in '

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips"

Lin 13 is 'visit rails_admin_path'.

If I delete line 10 ("Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver") everything runs as expected and the test is passing.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?